# How can I refactor this SVG animation to work in React?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I have this SVG animation that works with HTML and I need to get is to work in JSX, but am not getting any very useful results when I search for animation properties such as `ease` (can only find reference to ease-in and ease-out) and `forwards` to figure out how to refactor it.

My current HTML code:

```html
<svg>
  <rect
    id="gauge-limit-130"
    height="50%"
    width="100%"
    x="0"
    y="25%"
    className="front-gauge-limit gauge-no-budget"
    style="animation: 1.5s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running move;"
  >
  </rect>
<svg>
```

And my attempt at refactoring in to JSX:

```js
<svg>
  <rect
    id="gauge-limit-129"
    height="50%"
    width="29.66832437635357%"
    x="0"
    y="25%"
    className="front-gauge-limit gauge-under-budget"
    style={{ animation: '1.5s ease 0s 1 normal forwards running move' }}
    />
</svg>
```

The animation no longer works. How can I refactor it in to JSX?

Comment: Is the svg correct? I tried to run in a HTML editor,it is showing black box..

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Your jsx interpretation is spot on. Dont forget to add the original css as well.